# Return 4x4 named columns and rows of dupe count in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, multiple-columns

I'm trying to return a 4x4 grid of results of counts in the database. I'm counting all records and then also duplicate records under three criteria for four different columns.

For example I'm trying to get these various results to output at the same time:

```
select count(*)
from Table1

select count(*)
from Table1
where Firm is null

select count(*)
from Table1
where Firm is not null
group by Firm having count(*) > 1

select count(*)
from Table1
where Firm is null
group by Firm having count(*) > 1
```

The same mutations above will need to be applied to the code below

```
select count(*)
from Table2
where Office is not null
group by Office having count(*) > 1

select count(*)
from Table3
where ContactID is not null
  and record_type = 'T'
group by ContactID having count(*) > 1

select record_type, count(*)
from Table3
where ContactID is null
group by record_type
```

So while I can execute each of the query mutations individually and record each result as I return it, I would MUCH rather have a way to execute all sixteen counts at once. Is this possible? I've tried using UNIONs between the selections but apparently it doesn't even include dupes which makes it useless for me.

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated! Thanks

**Edit**: adding sample results, excel format for ease. would like only SQL results:

[![Desired Result Output (excel for display only)][1]][1]

Comment: Sample data and desired results (in text) would be most helpful

Comment: 4x4 grid?  What is in each row?  What is in each column?

Comment: `select count(*)
from Table1
where Firm is not null
group by Firm having count(*) > 1` returns a row for every double Firm.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti added desired results

Comment: Are you asking how to get a result set comprised of 16 unrelated queries returning a single number each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From context, it seems that your sql queries are in reality parallel to each other.  In other words, I take it that they repeat the same logic four times, just with different sources.  If so, then here's how I advise:

First, take your four sources and stack them into a single combined dataset.  This is what I do in the 'structured' CTE in the code below.  You'll want to only include relevant columns, and genericize the column names.  I chose the names 'source' and 'grouping' to indicate where the data is coming from and how it will be grouped conceptually in your logic.  Note the use of `union all` as opposed to simply `union` to prevent the processor from spending time trying to output distinct rows.  Also, I made an assumption as to how 'table3' translates to your sample output.  However, if I'm off, you know your data so hopefully you can correct as appropriate.

Second, make your necessary aggregations at the 'grouping' level.  This is what I do in the `groupedAggs` CTE.  This intermediate level is needed because of the need to identify duplicates within the groups.  Notice the use of case statements for the conditional logic, instead of entire subqueries referencing the same source multiple times.

Third, make your final level aggregations at the 'source' level to produce something like your sample output.

```
with structured as (

    select 'firms' as source, firm as grouping from table1 union all
    select 'offices', office from table2 union all
    select 'reps-total', contact from table3 where recordType = 't' union all
    select 'reps-individual', contact from table3 where recordType <> 't'

),

groupedAggs as (

    select      source, 
                grouping,
                total = count(*),
                linked = sum(case when grouping is not null then 1 else 0 end),
                dupes = case when count(*) > 1 then count(*) else 0 end
    from        structured
    group by    source,
                grouping

)

select      source, 
            total = sum(total),
            linked = sum(linked),
            unlinked = sum(total) - sum(linked),
            dupes = sum(dupes)
from        groupedAggs
group by    source
```

Comment: This is incredibly detailed and helpful! I'm going to plug away at it right now, but my work day is almost over. I will check back in tomorrow with an update on my success/failure! But conceptually you really nailed this. A lot to absorb and work with!

Comment: This worked exactly as described! Thank you. If I wanted to make any tweaks to the dupe logic, would it be possible for you to explain that section any further? If not, thanks for the help already!

Comment: Are you referring to `dupes = case when count(*) > 1 then count(*) else 0 end`?

Answer (score 0):

A result set comprised of 16 unrelated queries returning a single number each

```
   Select 1 as rn, 'Firms' as Title, (scalar_query_1-1) as Total, (scalar_query_1-2) as Linked, (scalar_query_1-3) as NotLinked, (scalar_query_1-4) as DupeSpIds
   union all
   Select 2, 'Offices', (scalar_query_2-1) , (scalar_query_2-2) , (scalar_query_2-3), (scalar_query_1-4)
   union all
   Select 3, 'Reps total', (scalar_query_3-1) , (scalar_query_3-2) , (scalar_query_3-3), (scalar_query_3-4)
   union all
   Select 4, 'Reps individual', (scalar_query_4-1) , (scalar_query_4-2) , (scalar_query_4-3), (scalar_query_4-4)
   Order by rn
```